# What would cause a negative number of currently loaded classes reported in JConsole?

Tags: java, tomcat

This is a bit of an odd problem, but we were noticing sluggish performance on a tomcat based server and after connecting JConsole, saw that is was reporting 'Current Classes Loaded' as a negative number. Any ideas on what might cause this?

Comment: got more than Integer.MAX_INT classes? ;)

Comment: no :) There appears to be a lot of classes being generated - but not quiet 2^32

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bug in JConsole's class counting.

Comment: Not sure this is 100% correct, but it seems like the only logical answer to me.